# positivity in bases of symmetric functions

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question, symmetric-functions

I've read conjectures concerning the positivity of certain symmetric polynomials, which ask if a symmetric polynomial has all nonnegative coefficients when written in some basis.  I'm curious what these mean combinatorially for the following bases:

m basis: monomial symmetric functions

e basis: elementary symmetric functions

p basis: power sum symmetric functions

s basis: Schur functions

For example, it is clear how to interpret the statement that the chromatic symmetric function is m-positive, but how would one interpret some of them being, say, e-positive?

Comment: In terms of the Schur basis, if the coefficients are positive integers, it means that your symmetric function is the (Fronenius) character of a representation of GL_n (or sl_n).